# Does Outlook need to be closed and reopened after adding full permissions to another mailbox?

Tags: exchange

When you add permission to another mailbox in Exchange the mailbox will appear in Outlook after awhile and begin downloading the mailbox.

What I'm wonder is if you have to close Outlook and open it back up for this mailbox to appear or if it will reappear without any interaction?

Stupid question I know - testing on my own end as we speak but I'm not sure how long I should wait before coming to the conclusion that Outlook must first be closed and reopened for a new mailbox to appear.

Comment: You will need to log out of outlook, esp if you are using cached outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on a combination of Exchange and Outlook, and the answer can vary depending on what versions you have of each.

Server Side (Exchange):
In general, it can take a minimum of 2 hours to propagate mailbox/permission changes.  This is mostly due to the Information Store Cache refresh time (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998523.aspx) with a default period of 2 hours.  The replication of these permissions can vary across a network, depending on how complicated it is and how many servers it needs to replicate to, and which server the indented mailbox resides on.  You can change the settings in the registry, but it may have adverse effects on your server (if you decide to go this route, make sure to backup your registry first!).

Client Side (Outlook):
In general, if Cached Exchange Mode is enabled, Outlook automatically refreshes the cache every 24 hours (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/troubleshoot-cached-exchange-mode-HP001000078.aspx).  You can manually update the cache yourself by clearing it and letting it pull down the latest info (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2554329).